# Parsing grep output

Tags: php, linux, shell, grep

I'm trying to make a server manager and here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$COMMAND = shell_exec('ps ax --format command | grep skulltag');
$arr = explode("./",$COMMAND);
$text = shell_exec('pgrep -u doom');
$arrtext = preg_split('/\s+/', $text);
 for( $i = 1; $i < count($arr); $i++ ) {
    echo $i,". PROCESS ID ",$arrtext[$i]," Command issued: ",$arr[$i];
    echo '<br>';
 }
?>
```

As you can see, I'm separating the $COMMAND string with ./ (file execution). However, for some reason at the end of the list there's this:

```
sh -c ps ax --format command | grep skulltag grep skulltag
```

Here is the full output for reference:

> 1. PROCESS ID 4793 Command issued: skulltag-server
> 2. PROCESS ID 4956 Command issued: skulltag-server -port 13000
> 3. PROCESS ID 4958 Command issued: skulltag-server -port 13001 sh -c
>      ps ax --format command | grep skulltag grep skulltag

What would be the easiest and most effective way to get rid of that line, and how would I do it? Thanks.

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, the canonical solution to this is to use a pattern which doesn't match itself, e.g. `grep [s]kulltag`.

Comment: "for some reason" — that would be because the command you are running  is running, so it shows up in the list of running processes.

Comment: If you have `pgrep`, why do you want to reimplement it?

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
ps ax --format command | grep skulltag
```

To this:

```
ps ax --format command | grep [s]kulltag
```

That way, the grep command itself contains the string '[s]kultag', which is not matched by the grep regular expression '[s]kultag'.

Also, two suggestions: 1. there's no guarantee that your initial ps | grep and your later pgrep will line up. Instead, use a single pgrep:

```
pgrep -afl skulltag
```

And 2. your for loop starts with 1, which will skip the process in arr[0].

Your php could be rewritten something like this:

```
$processes = explode("\n", shell_exec('pgrep -afl skulltag'));
foreach($processes as $i => $process) {
    ($pid, $command) = explode(' ',$process,2);
    echo $i+1,". PROCESS ID ",$pid," Command issued: ",$command;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My quick and dirty solution is to append `| grep -v grep` to the command.

Comment: Fixing the regex is more elegant.